# Undefined value after conversion from JSON array to object

Tags: javascript

I have JSON array with one object consisting of nodes and links.

```
data = [Object]=[ { nodes: Array[..] ,links: Array[…] } ]
```

This is all fine, but for accessing the links for example I have to use data[0].links, which is a bit annoying. I would like the array to be an object, so that data.links gives access to the links. I have tried to set:

```
data = data[0];
```

But then the array of Objects, data.links, are displayed as "undefined".It seems like when a specific element is accessed the value is displayed, for example `data.links[3].name`. Why is that?

Edit:

More specifically:

if data = [ { nodes: Array[... ] ,links: Array[...] } ] =>

```
console.log(data[0].links); //shows the data[0].links[0].name = value in the console
```

if data = { nodes: Array[... ] ,links: Array[...] }  =>

```
console.log(data.links); //shows data[0].links[0].name = undefined
```

but interestingly

```
console.log(data.links[0].name); //shows the correct value.
```

Comment: What is this notation?  In JS, `[Object]` is an array containing the builtin object constructor, and `Array[foo]` looks up the property on the `Array` constructor whose name is the result of evaluating `foo`.

Comment: _'then the array of Objects, data.links, are displayed as "undefined"'_ - Displayed how? Please show more of your code, and perhaps a more real-world example of your data that is actually valid JS. For the data you show, after doing `data=data[0]` if you say `data.links` it will give you the links array, so then you'd have to access the individual links with `data.links[0]`, etc. (By the way, there is no JSON anywhere in your question - JSON is a string format.)

Comment: @nnnnnn: I edited the questions to clarify things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of solutions:

If you control the JSON output, simply remove the enclosing brackets `[]` those are basically wrapping your object in an array.

```
data = { nodes: [...] ,links: [...] };
```

If you don't control the JSON just simply assign the zero index of the array to the variable you actually want to work with.

```
json = [ { nodes: [...] ,links: [...] } ];
data = json[0];
```

Unfortunately, 'links' is an array. To access a member of that array, you will need to access its index value.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, directly setting it without the brackets works fine. However, I still have the same issue with the undefined values in the nodes and links arrays when looking at the object in developer tools. For example: data.nodes[1].name = "undefined".

Comment: @graphmeter - That's because `nodes` is an array and doesn't have a `name` property - the items _in_ the array have a `name` property (presumably; you don't show it in the question). You have to say `data.nodes[0].name` for the first one; use a variable in a loop to access each in turn.